# How can I change the initial orientation of a physics image without affecting its physics body?

Tags: javascript, phaser-framework

Making my first Phaser game, using v3. It's an Asteroids clone, as a learning project.

I drew my own spaceship, so I have a png of that. I hadn't read the Phaser docs yet, hadn't been warned about Phaser's right-handedness, and so my spaceship faces northward.

Now I've rigged that image up as an arcade physics body, and the arrow keys control the throttle and rudder. The main camera follows the png. Massive success... except that, when the game loads, the spaceship is visibly pointing north, but accelerating straight "ahead" causes it to slide eastward (towards physics rotation 0).

I don't want to change my image. I want to learn how to Phaser this because it seems like a pretty basic item in the toolkit: how to configure Phaser so it groks the assets I beg, borrow, or steal, as they are.

I'm hoping this is enough:

```js
preload() {
    this.load.image('player.ship.facingNorth', 'assets/images/player/ship-facingNorth.png')
}

create() {
    // this image faces north (i.e. png angle = -90)
    this.player = this.physics.add.image(VW_50, VH_50, 'player.ship.facingNorth')

    // somehow tell phaser to rotate the image clockwise 90 degress

    // this.player.angle = 90 // rotates visible pixels AND physics orientation -- they stay inconsistent
    // this.player.body.angle = -90 // no effect
    // this.player.body.transform.angle = 90 // no effect
    // this.player.facing = 0.4 // no effect
    // this.player.body.facing = 0.4 // no effect
    // this.player.body.transform.facing = 0.4 // no effect
    // this.player.preRotation = 0.7 // no effect
    // this.player.body.preRotation = 0.7 // no effect
    // this.player.body.transform.preRotation = 0.7 // no effect

    this.cameras.main.startFollow(this.player, false, 0.1, 0.1, 0, 10)
    this.cursors = this.input.keyboard.createCursorKeys()
}

update(time, delta) {
    // ... cursor keys logic

    const thrust = 100

    if (this.rudder !== 0) {
        this.player.rotation += this.rudder
    }

    this.physics.velocityFromRotation(this.player.rotation, thrust, this.player.body.velocity)
}
```

I've looked at the docs for [Physics.Arcade.Body](https://photonstorm.github.io/phaser3-docs/Phaser.Physics.Arcade.Image.html), [Physics.Arcade.Image](https://photonstorm.github.io/phaser3-docs/Phaser.Physics.Arcade.Body.html), and 
[Phaser.GameObjects.GameObject](https://photonstorm.github.io/phaser3-docs/Phaser.GameObjects.GameObject.html). That's everything I could think to try.

Is there any way to keep using a north-facing image, and align the visible graphic with the physics-managed velocity?

I imagine I could apply some kind of matrix transform to some sort of world-level thing (not sure of the details), but it seems like that approach wouldn't last very long if I end up using assets from multiple sources with different conventions.

Any help is appreciated.